# where column = NULL and whereNotIn not working together in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

My code not working together, but if i only use one of them`->where('numbers.client_group_id', NULL)` OR `->whereNotIn('id', function($query) use ($request){` itu work normal.

```
$model = DB::table('numbers')->select('id','phone');

    $model
      ->where('numbers.client_group_id', NULL)
      ->whereNotIn('id', function($query) use ($request){
        $query->select('number_push_logs.number_id')->from('number_push_logs')->where('number_push_logs.client_group_id',$request->client_group);
      })
      ->orderBy('quality', 'asc')->limit($request->total_push);
```

this my table looks like:

#### `numbers` table

```
| id| phone      | client_group_id|
|---|------------|----------------|
| 1 |0852176255**| 1              |
| 2 |0852176255**| 1              |
| 3 |0852176255**| NULL           |
```

#### `number_push_logs` table

```
| id| number_id  |client_group_id |
|---|------------|----------------|
| 1 |1           | 1              |
| 2 |1           | 2              |
| 3 |2           | 2              |
```

so i want to select numbers data where client_group_id = NULL and id numbers not in number_push_log table with specific client_group_id

Comment: Think you may benefit from [A quick look at the docuemntation](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/wherenull-vs-wherecolumn-null) which covers this exact situation `->whereNull('column')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this. Use join. It performs better than nested demand.

```php
       \DB::table('numbers as n')
            ->select('id','phone') 
            ->leftJoin('number_push_logs as npl', 'n.client_group_id', '=', 'npl.client_group_id')
            ->whereNull('npl.id')
            ->orderBy('quality', 'asc')
            ->limit($request->total_push);
```

Comment: Wow thank u it give more speed, btw i have 8 million row.

Comment: Make sure you have an index on the 'client_group_id' fields in both tables for higher performance.